# Ruby on rails / Ampps / mysql.sock missing?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ampps

I just launch a project in **Ruby on Rails**, everything working until I go on  :

> localhost:3000

An error is displayed :

> Unknown MySQL server host '/Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql.sock'

So you'll say to me, just find the **mysql.sock**, it's maybe not the right path but if i write in my terminal :

> sudo find / -name "mysql.sock"

The result is : **/Applications/AMPPS/var/mysql.sock**

So i don't really understand why my console return me this file while Rails is not agree with that ? And the worst is that i don't find the file in **/Applications/AMPPS/var/** ... I really don't understand at all.

I have **ampps** installed on my **osx**, is maybe a conflict ?

Answer (score 0):

your mysql service doesn't start, please start your mysql service and it should work